# Can't get what I want from a for-loop in template?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templates

I have template like this:

```
{% for a in As%}
    <div>blah--blah--</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="doSomeThingTarget" value={{a.xx}}>
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="doSomeThing">
{% endfor%}
```

The loop may execute couple of times, and show some submit buttons.

In python file, I code:

```
target = self.request.get('doSomeThingTarget')
```

You know, I try to use `value={{a.xx}}` to hold the value in a particular loop, so, when I click one of the buttons, I can figure out what's target I need to process. BUT whichever I click, I just get the value of the first loop. What's wrong with my code? How can I implement my intention?

Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry, I have deleted my unswer, because my idea was wrong, I see it now after testing it.

Comment: @DaneSoul It doesn't work for me. I write a small MySubmit:  alert("The value of this submit button is " + document.forms[0].doSomeThingTarget.value); But when I click one button, the alert windows shows it got the value that is undefined.

Comment: @Yes, I try it too. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining a single form, with multiple copies of a hidden input element with the same name. As a result, you only get the one copy (though if you used `get_all`, you'd get an array of all of them).

Instead, you should include the form start and end tags inside the loop, making each iteration its own form.

Comment: <form action='index.php' method='get' name='myform'>
<input type='submit' name='submit1' value='first_submit'>
<input type='submit' name='submit1' value='second_submit'>
</form> - Such code works correctly and pass propper value...

Comment: Awesome! Thanks both Nick and DaneSoul. :)